# A-Frame entities with "shadow" component - materials "side:double" display moire patterns

Tags: aframe

If the "shadow" component is applied to an entity and its material is set to <"side: double> a moire pattern appears.

The red sphere in this scene has shadow applied and material set to `side:double` I've also applied it to the ground plane - same

A-Frame version 0.9.2

https://stackoverflow-side-double-shadow.glitch.me/

Is this a bug, or a feature which I don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

There's a three.js `.shadowSide` property to the material you can use https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.

`el.getObject3D('mesh').material.shadowSide = THREE.FrontSide`